# Syntastic NASM Checker

Tags: vim, syntastic

So I've been doing some work in my Assembly class for college, and I use Vim as my primary code editor. I'm having a problem with Syntastic where I'm writing assembly for NASM, but Syntastic only wants to run the gcc error checker (which tells me all my code is wrong). I tried to run the NASM checker explicitly with `SyntasticCheck nasm` but that didn't seem to work. I also attempted to `let g:syntastic_asm_checkers = ['nasm']` in my .vimrc but that didn't seem to do anything. How can I get Syntastic to run the NASM checker here?

As a note, I tested this by just writing something like `mov eax,` to get an error out of NASM.

Comment: `:set ft?` what it shows?

Comment: Did you look at the [list of checkers](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Syntax-Checkers#user-content-nasm)? `nasm` is a checker for filetype `nasm`, not `asm`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr : Vim shows that it wasn't detecting the filetype when I was entering your command. I did some more research and apparently it's a known problem that Vim doesn't detect the .nasm filetype as detailed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=697049). Everything worked again after I ```set filetype=nasm```. Thanks!

@SatoKatsura : You were right, nasm is a checker for filetype nasm. For some reason I was under the impression that I could still run it anyway. I'll have to look more into getting vim to recognize the nasm filetype...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, it turns out `nasm` only works for files with a nasm file extension. After renaming my file to `<file>.nasm` I discovered that vim doesn't automatically detect the `nasm` filetype after running `set ft?`, so I'll have to modify my .vimrc to support the extension.

Comment: you can type `:autocmd BufRead` and `:autocmd BufEnter` and find filetypedetect section to check if your vim implementation recognize the file extension or it is a real bug.

Answer (score 4):

You need to either

- force the association between `.asm` with nasm.  Just add this anywhere in your .vimrc

  ```
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.asm set filetype=nasm
  ```
- use the `.nasm` extension. Then everything will just work.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the file `nasm.vim` in `~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/nasm` to work for asm and saved the edited file in `~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/asm` with the same name `nasm.vim`. Doing so, you can put `let g:syntastic_asm_checkers = ['nasm']` into your `.vimrc` configuration and it works just fine :)

You can find the edited file as well as some details on https://srv2.mysnet.me/casm/tutorial/vim-configuration.

Well, I know that it has been a few years old question, but it'll help others at east, I hope. (at least I was looking for an answer myself until I figured out tweaking the files might work out thanks to @netskink :D)

Answer (score -1):

For what its worth, I tried to dork with the files:

```
plugins/syntastic/registry.vim
syntax_checkers/nasm/nasm.vim
syntax_checkers/asm/gcc.vim
```

To disable .asm syntax and replace it with nasm syntax but it did not work.  I could the errors to go away but I could not get the snytax coloring or checker to work automatically.  I reverted my changes and just do this instead:

```
:SyntasticCheck nasm
:set filetype=nasm
:SyntasticCheck nasm
```

After the second syntasticcheck command, it will have syntax coloring and nasm syntax checking enabled.  Not sure why it takes two passes.